# Variable is incremented twice in node.js http callback function

Tags: node.js, callback, increment

I was playing around with node.js and something strange happens when you run this code:

```
var http = require("http");
var i = 0;

function onRequest(request, response) {  
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("You're number " + i++);
  response.end();
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
```

I would expect it to behave like a page views counter, but with each refresh of the browser tab i get the result of what seems to be `i=i+2` instead of a simple increment. Could someone explain this behavior to me?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your browser is hitting your server for `favicon.ico` as well.  Each request increments `i`, and the request for `favicon.ico` counts.

Use a tool such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see this behavior yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I bet it's the favicon request that browsers love to send over and over again.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it did 2 requests, but didn't know why. :D