# Starting with node.js, creating a simple http server, callback not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am starting with node.js. [This is the book](http://www.nodebeginner.org/) I am following. The first example is creating a simple http server. The author explains the code meticulously, and he starts modifying the original example step-by-step. The problem I am having is in the section with heading: *"Event-driven asynchronous callbacks"*. The piece of code in question is here:

```
var http = require("http");

function onRequest(request, response) {
  console.log("Request received.");
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);

console.log("Server has started.");
```

The only changes I made to the code are cosmetic. But just for the sake of clarity, here is my piece:

```
var http = require("http"),
    port = 1337;

function doHandleRequest(request, response) {
  console.log("Request received...");
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Welcome to Node.js Kickstart!");
  response.end();
}

http.createServer(doHandleRequest).listen(port);
console.log("Listening at http://127.0.0.1:" + port + "\n");
```

Anyway, every time I refresh the page, the *Request received...* message should be displayed once (?), however, the message is logged **twice**. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131112/variable-is-incremented-twice-in-node-js-http-callback-function

same question, your bowser also request for fav.ico

Comment: Thank you. I Googled it but I was doing it wrong. I should do more extensive search before coming here and posting a question. Can someone please mark this as a duplicate?

Comment: someone will do it for you, I have post a screen shot for you, it's really hard to tell without debug, choose a ide will make your life easy :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't actually Node's fault. This would be your browser's fault.

When you load a page, your browser also makes a request to `<domain:port>/favicon.ico`, to try and nab the site's favicon image (the little images displayed in the tab)

For example, https://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico.

That would be why this is happening.

Comment: Is it possible to determine which request is which and not count the request for favicon? I suppose it would require looking into the properties of "request" object, wouldn't it? I guess I'll find an answer as I follow the book, but could you (or anyone else) please write a little more about it anyway?

Comment: yes, it's in the `url` property of `request` object

Answer (score 2):

[image: first request]

[image: second request]

as you can see there are two request one is for '/' another is for '/favicon.ico', I'm use eclipse to debug the code

Answer (score 0):

When your browser requests the URL, it will also request '/favicon.ico', giving your server 2 requests.